# Pandas - Store multiple values in one cell

Tags: python, data-structures, pandas, dataframe

I have answers from a questionnaire, and I start using pandas to process them.

So far it looks like:

```
In[1]:

questionnaire = pd.DataFrame([{'age': 72, 'sex': 'M'},
                              {'age': 80, 'sex': 'F'}],
                             index=[np.array(['patient1', 'patient2'])])
questionnaire


Out[1]:

           age sex
 patient1   72   M
 patient2   80   F


In[2]:

questionnaire.groupby('sex').size()

Out[2]:

sex
F      1
M      1
```

My issue is that this questionnaire also comes with open questions, that will receive multiple answers.

So I would like to somehow store these multiple values in one cell, such as:

```
In[3]:

questionnaire = pd.DataFrame([{'age': 72, 'sex': 'M',
                               'activites': ['sleep', 'eat']},
                              {'age': 80, 'sex': 'F',
                               'activites': ['sleep', 'walk']}],
                             index=[np.array(['patient1', 'patient2'])])
questionnaire


Out[3]:

               activites age sex
 patient1   [sleep, eat]  72   M
 patient2  [sleep, walk]  80   F
```

And I would expect something like:

```
In[?]:

questionnaire.groupby('activities').size()

Out[?]:

activities
eat    1
sleep  2
walk   1
```

But my attempt in [3] does not work, as array are only considered as "objects" in the dataframe.

I probably think of it the wrong way. Is there any data structure that would allow me to have multiple values from one question, for one patient ?

Comment: Probably better to have multiple rows for each patient.  Have one row with "sleep, 72, M", another row for the same patient with "eat, 72, M".  Change your "patient1" field from an index to just a normal column that will indicate "patient ID".

Comment: In a normal database scheme we would resolve this with two tables. One that goes from `patient_id` to all the patient's info, and another that has an index on `(patient_id, question_id)` to `answer`.

Comment: I was planning on approaching this problem by creating multiple df's like @U2EF1 said, and then just merge them on either name or unique ID, much like you would do with a db. I think you should be able to use the pandas.merge(df1, df2, on='identifier') to link them together.